# Seaborn boxplot and Violinplot median is different

Tags: seaborn

I am comparing a boxplot and violin plot in seaborn and the violin plot has a different inner box than the boxplot itself.  I would like to use a violin plot to visualize the distribution of the data at the same time, is it possible the violin plot has a different median due to the kernel density estimation?  The boxplots have the correct median from the data.

EDIT:
when I set `inner='quartiles'` the violin plots show the appropriate scale.  I would like to use `inner='box'` though for appearances if I can.
Here are the graphs themselves:

[image]

and now the boxplot:
[image]

Comment: Reduce this down to a clear example with included data. There's so much to look at with that plot and at first glance, the medians look fine.

Comment: And read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: will do, the medians look fine for the first 3, but for `RGR` and `SWIR32` they are clearly off.

Comment: That's not clear to me. The scales have clearly been manipulated in someway, and I expect that's the source of the perceived error. Without a working example that demonstrates the problem, it's otherwise impossible to do much else than speculate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "the scales have clearly been manipulated in someway, and I expect that's the source of the perceived error. Without a working example that demonstrates the problem, it's otherwise impossible to do much else than speculate."